# creating a oop php blog

Tags: php, oop

Hi Im trying to develop a oop php driven blog. Im new to the oop way in php so its going quite slow. I have a class BlogPost were I have created the private variables for the rows in my blog field in he db and getters and setters for them example:

```
function getCreated() {
    return $this-$created;
}

function setCreated($created) {
     $this->$created = $created;
}
```

is this the way to do it?! I think Im on the right track but Im not sure. Do anyone have any input?! maybe some tips on good tutorials on how to create a blog oop php style. Found one at net.tuts but Im not really liking it. Thanks!

Regards

Comment: why don't you use something wordpress?

Comment: One of the core principles of programming is Don't reinvent the wheel. Unless your blog engine is solving something that hasn't been solved yet in the problem domain of blogging engines, why not resort to a readily available engine then?

Comment: @jigfox and @gordon: normally I wouldnt do it but this is part of a course Im taking so its mandatory. The assignment is to build a blog oop php style.

Comment: @Gordon I'm sure you'll have written something in code that has already been done before. Writing solutions like this from scratch is a good method of learning, as you then understand why something is built the way it is, and leads to solving problems in other people's code faster.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are close, try

```
function getCreated() {
    return $this->created;
}

function setCreated($created) {
     $this->created = $created;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your feedback I should have known that, a minor typo we can call that:). One thing though how would you create the constructor for this? I was thinking something like this:     public function __construct($id, $created, $modified, $author, $title, $body) {
  $this->$id =
 }

Comment: and again the typo: `$this->$id` should be `$this->id`

Comment: Yeah, just get rid of the dollar sign infront of the property.  $this->$id would look for a property with the same name as the value in the variable $id, which you don't want.

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I avoid getters and settings and just use public properties. I then use the `__set()` magic method to listen for properties being set and add the key to a private `$dirty` array. I can then loop over these when saving a record. For example:

```
class BlogPost {

    public $id;
    public $title;
    public $content;

    private $dirty;

    function __set($key, $value) {
        $this->$key = $value;
        $this->dirty[] = $key;
    }

    function save() {
        if (isset($this->id) && intval($this->id) > 0) {
            // do UPDATE query
        } else {
            // do INSERT query
        }
    }
}
```

Then to use:

```
$id = (isset($_GET['id'])) ? intval($_GET['id']) : null;

$post = new BlogPost();
$post->title = $_POST['title'];
$post->content = $_POST['content'];
$post->save();
```

Very primitive, but should give you an idea of how to implement this theory for yourself.